# woocommerce base location condition to match current user location

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like some help on this

basically I would like to have a condition set for customers outside the base location in woocommerce

for instance, my base location is united kingdom

so how would I make a condition for it like this

```
if (user) = united kingdom {
echo 'customer is in UK';
} else {
echo 'customer is outside uk';
}
```

Thanks

also how to use this;

wc_get_customer_default_location()
wc_get_base_location()

currently I got this and not working

```
$country_match = wc_get_customer_default_location();
echo 'Your location is ' . $country_match['country'] . '<br>';

if ( $country_match ) {
    $default = wc_get_base_location();
    if ( $default['country'] !== $country_match ) {
        echo 'country match<br>';
    } else { 
        echo 'country do not match<br>'; }

    if ( $default['state'] && $default['state'] !== $state ) {
        echo 'state match';
    } else { echo 'state do not match'; }
} else {
    echo 'false';
    }
```

Comment: can someone help me on this, please